# Determining if point on boundary using shapely?

Tags: point, shapely, point-in-polygon, boundaries

I'm new to Python, and I want to test if a certain point lies ON the (boundary) of a polygon - not inside, not outside, just if it's on the boundary.
The points and polygon already defined

```
polygon = [(3, 2), (5, 1), (7, 2), (8, 6), (9, 7), (11, 6), (10, 4), (12, 2), (15, 2), (16, 5), (19, 7), (18, 11), (14, 12), (11, 9), (5, 9), (2, 6)] 
Point_X = 14
Point_Y = 12
```

this point should be a boundary.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Due to the imprecision associated with floating-point values, far fewer points which are "on" a line will actually be reported as such in real-world situations. If you want to test this, your code needs to use ArcPy  functions to assemble `Polygon` and `PointGeometry` objects, so that you can cast the Polygon to a line (using `Geometry.boundary()`) and test for point intersection with `Geometry.contains()`. Be sure to specify an appropriate `SpatialReference`.

Comment: You had a tag for ArcPy but your question body and title make no mention that it is being used so I am removing it.

Comment: I'm also adding a tag for shapely to match the answer. If you are not using that library then please ask a new and more focused question.

Comment: @PolyGeo You've altered the question twice to make it fit an answer that did not help the OP, and in so doing, made my comment nonsensical. This was not a greatest moment in moderation.

Comment: @Vince comments are meant to be temporary so stranding one is easily addressed by deleting it. Retrofitting of this question to its only answer creates a Q&A that may have value to future searchers.  A clearer question would have offered a clearer path to answering it.

Comment: @PolyGeo The real value in my comment was not reflected in the answer. If you're going to edit the question to make the answer acceptable, you should edit the comments as well (which is something I can't do)

Comment: @Vince I agree that it is unfortunate that the value of your comment was largely lost but the alternative was to lose the value of an existing answer. Fulfilling our goal of creating a library of clear answers to clear questions offers different paths some times.

Comment: @Vince an overnight thought is that the value of your comment could be preserved by writing an ArcPy equivalent question to the current state of this one and using it as a self-answer.

Comment: @Vince I've now approximated a self-answered ArcPy equivalent Q&A at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268120

Comment: @PolyGeo Saw that. Busy day here today, and probably tomorrow. I'll see if I can do better while caged at home after the snow storm.

Comment: @Vince I'll happily delete my answer there (and all our comments here) if/when you get a chance to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using shapely, based on the shapely documentation. https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#binary-predicates

```
from shapely import geometry

polygon = [(3, 2), (5, 1), (7, 2), (8, 6), (9, 7), (11, 6), (10, 4), (12, 2), (15, 2), (16, 5), (19, 7), (18, 11), (14, 12), (11, 9), (5, 9), (2, 6)] 
Point_X = 14
Point_Y = 12

line = geometry.LineString(polygon)
point = geometry.Point(Point_X, Point_Y)

print(line.contains(point))
```

Comment: The original question was unclear, but it was tagged "arcpy",  which was an indication that this answer would not be useful to the OP. Please hold off on answering unclear questions, since it is not usual that a question is altered to make the inappropriate answer correct.

Comment: Doc URL mentioned above is now at:
https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#predicates-and-relationships