# Determining if point on boundary using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geometry

From comments at [Determining if point on boundary using shapely?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267986) I am creating an ArcPy equivalent Q&A to that one which was answered for shapely.  Quoting the asker of the original question:

> I'm new to Python, and I want to test if a certain point lies ON the
>   (boundary) of a polygon - not inside, not outside, just if it's on the
>   boundary. The points and polygon already defined

```
polygon = [(3, 2), (5, 1), (7, 2), (8, 6), (9, 7), (11, 6), (10, 4), (12, 2), (15, 2), (16, 5), (19, 7), (18, 11), (14, 12), (11, 9), (5, 9), (2, 6)] 
Point_X = 14
Point_Y = 12
```

> this point should be a boundary. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @Vince on the original question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267986/determining-if-point-on-boundary-using-shapely?noredirect=1#comment425888_267986):

> Due to the imprecision associated with floating-point values, far
>   fewer points which are "on" a line will actually be reported as such
>   in real-world situations. If you want to test this, your code needs to
>   use ArcPy  functions to assemble `Polygon` and `PointGeometry`
>   objects, so that you can cast the Polygon to a line (using
>   `Geometry.boundary()`) and test for point intersection with
>   `Geometry.contains()`. Be sure to specify an appropriate
>   `SpatialReference`.

Comment: I'd used distance to method. That way a tolerance can be introduced.

Comment: I second @FelixIP, I've always used within a distance for points on lines. You could use Near/Generate Near Table if you have an advanced license but I find it much easier to buffer the boundary then select the points that intersect the buffer (Geometry.boundary().buffer(Some_very_small_distance))